# adding pushbutton to already existing templates

Tags: itext

Am trying to put an image on the existing itext pdf using Acrofields( The templates are already deployed at client location, I can't use any other way to get image on the existing itext templates other than using the acrofields so please suggest me using the acrofields..).
Can I know the how to create a pushbutton in already existing template and to add an image on to it..

Thanks in advance